# How can I set auto-casting using hotkeys?

Tags: starcraft-2, keyboard

Is there a way to set an SCV to auto-repair, or a carrier to auto-build interceptors completely with hotkeys?

I believe the question is also interesting for standard hotkeys but I use grid hotkeys.

Comment: do both of the answers below work?  why upvotes on both very different answers?

Comment: For me, `alt` worked, so that's the one I accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually it's `alt` + `key`

One nice usage of it (besides of auto-repair and auto-making inteceptors for Carrier) it's an auto-unborrow on banelings so they unborrows as some unit is nearby thus acting like landmine without need to control them.

Answer (score 8):

The hotkey for autocasting an action is the action's hotkey with `Ctrl`.

If `R` is the hotkey for Repair, `Ctrl-R` will be the hotkey to toggle Repair autocasting.